# SumConvergence fails in version 10

Tags: version-10, summation, assumptions

```
SumConvergence[(-1)^(n + 1) ((Cos[n^2] + Sin[n + 2])/7^n), n]
```

Mathematica fails to provide a result (true/false) but wolfram alpha works. What should I do ?

It gives 
$$\text{SumConvergence}\left[(-1)^{n+1} 7^{-n} \left(\cos \left(n^2\right)+\sin (n+2)\right),n\right]$$

Comment: Mathematica 9.0.1 gives `True` though.  Can you mention your precise Mathematica version?  I assume 10.0.2.

Comment: yes 10.0.0.0 version

Comment: Please mention that in the question.  Unrelated: you really should upgrade to 10.0.2.  It won't fix this problem but it will fix many others.

Comment: Version 8 doesn't give a result, so it looks 9 is unique in this.

Comment: Fixed in V11.2.0